# change AWS AMI Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

is it possible to use the aws cli to change an AMI name?

I can successfully add a "Name" tag (using aws ec2 create-tags) but not change the "AMI Name" that shows on the web UI.
This is an imported AMI so the AMI Name is something like
import-ami-XXXXX.

I've tried:

`aws ec2 modify-image-attribute --image-id AMI_ID --attribute Name --value VALUE`

but I'm getting back a:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the ModifyImageAttribute operation: No attributes specified.
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not possible to change the name of an AMI image. Once the name is set, it cannot be changed.

You have 2 possible resolutions:

1. Create the AMI image again, using a different name. However, in your case, the name may be automatically generated and this may not be an option.
2. Copy the AMI within the same region, giving the copy a more desirable name.

Comment: thanks Matt. Looks like option 2 is the closest I can get.

Answer (score 0):

I see two name like fields in the EC2 console for AMIs. One called "Name" and another one called "AMI Name". The latter is immutable, as the previous answer suggests.

BUT, I was able to set the "Name" field by using create-tags as shown below:

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources AMI_ID --tags Key=Name,Value=bbb
```

Comment: thanks. The "Name" is the tag which can be changed without issues. It's the "AMI Name" I was interested on.